# Magento: ftp account creation on new user created

Tags: php, magento, ftp

I want to create a ftp account using `php`, when a user creates on magento. I am interested to create new extension for this. So in which model do I have to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it simply using JSON.